# Help With Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am achieving the wrong answer, but I am unsure where I went wrong about it.
I am given a conservative vector field and the line $C$: $$F = \langle \frac{4x}{y^2+1}, -\frac{4y(x^2+1)}{(y^2+1)^2} \rangle, C \textrm{ is parameterized by } x=t^3-1, y=t^6-t, 0 \le t \le 1  .$$

Since I know it is conservative, I find the potential function $f$: $$\frac{4x^2+2}{y^2+1} + c$$

Then I just apply FTLI, $f(x(1), y(1)) - f(x(0), y(0))$ by recognizing $t$ is in between $0$ and $1$ therefore its initial point must be $(-1,0)$ and its terminal point $(0,0)$. So I get $2 - 6 = -4$, but $-4$ is deemed wrong.

I am not sure when I went wrong in this, I double checked my integrals for $P$ and $Q$ when getting the potential function, did I go wrong in determining the initial and terminal points?

Comment: $(x(0),y(0))=(-1,0)$ and $(x(1),y(1))=(0,0)$, not $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, respectively.

Comment: Check your potential function by calculating grad f, at least a factor 2 is wrong.Also your initial and final points are wrong put 0 and 0 in the equation of x,y

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry, I realized a typo in the problem statement -> $x = t^3 - 1$, not plus. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pontential is not correct, it should be $$f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2+2}{y^2+1}.$$ Also, $$f((x(1),y(1))=f(0,0)=2,$$ and $$f(x(0),y(0))=f(-1,0)=4,$$ so the correct answer is $2-4=-2.$

Comment: Oh I see, my integral in terms of x for $\frac{4x}{y^2+1}$ I got $\frac{2x^2}{y^2+1}$ and then  for the integral in terms of y for $-\frac{4y(x^2+1)}{y^2+1}$, I achieved $\frac{2x^2+2}{y^2+1}$ and seeing how the numerator differed by a $+ 2$, I thought I had to add those together, but I see I didn't since $2x^2$ is still common between the two integrals. Thank you.

Comment: @CodedRoses Here is a way to think about it. You probably were prone to making that mistake because you first calculated that $$f = \frac{2x^2}{y^2+1}+C$$ from integrating $P$. But remember $C$ is an arbitrary function of $y$, not an arbitrary constant because of how partial differentiation works. So it would've been equally correct to put the $+C$ over the common denominator $$f = \frac{2x^2+C}{y^2+1}$$ because the denominator is $y$-only and can be absorbed into the constant. Just something to think about as you go on to deal with more complicated (or higher dimensional) potential functions.

Comment: congrats for hitting $8$k rep

Comment: Oh, thank you! :)